# django not nullable error on model field containing null-True

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models, models

So i have a user that can post comments on effects, im linking up my models and i keep getting the non-nullable error no matter what ive tried.  Everyone says it needs to have null=True.  It isn't working lol.  What am I not seeing here?

This is the official error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: effect_modules_comment__new.author_id
```

And my models:

```
class Effect_module(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    html = models.TextField(default='')
    css = models.TextField(default='')
    js = models.TextField(default='')
    up_votes = models.IntegerField()
    down_votes = models.IntegerField()
    effect_author = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    effects = models.ManyToManyField(Effect_module)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(default='No Comment Here')
    effect_object = models.ForeignKey(Effect_module)
```

Comment: Try including `blank=True`.

Comment: i added blank=True and during makemigrations, it asked me to provide the default what should i add to that? it wouldn't allow me to enter null=True or anything so i just used that suggested timezone.now() lol and now its still saying nullable error on migrate

Comment: Did you add the foreignkey after the Comment model itself? Do you already have comments in the db?

Comment: yeah i did...i had a feeling i just messed something up with the migrations and stuff so i just cleared the DB..it was just dummy data anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete all migration scripts. Add `null=True` means it can be NULL in the database, `blank=True` means that it can be left blank in forms.

Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```